# Run failed/segmentation fault BinaryTree c++

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

So I found that there's a problem with my insert method that causes segmentation fault but have no idea where or how to solve it.

My insert method is like this:

```
NodeTree* BinarySearchTree::insert(NodeTree *node,int element){
    NodeTree *current;

    if(empty()){
        root->setElement(element);  //Si es null creem l'arrel i la retornem
        root->setParent(current);     
        return root;             
    }
    if(node!=nullptr){
        current=node;      //Si el node no és null l'igualem amb un auxiliar 
                           //que despres serà retornat segons el contigut del node
    }
    if(element<=node->getElement()){
        current=node;                                      //els elements més petits a l'esquera
        node->setLeft(insert(node->getLeft(),element)); // crida recursiva
    }
    else{
        current=node;                                       // elements més grans a la dreta
        node->setRight(insert(node->getRight(),element));//crida recursiva
    }


    return node; //un cop fet el procediment anterior retorna el node
```

Where empty() is return root==nullptr;

Also my main.cpp where the problem is caused:

```
case 1:
    cout<<"Numero a afegir: "; cin>>num; cout<<""<<endl;
    if(tree.empty()){
       root->setElement(num);
    }
    tree.insert(root,num);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if complete code would have been shared anyway there are couple of mistakes with the code,

Segfault is happening most likely because of below statement will always be false base case never satisfies and then code goes below and uses null pointer as below condition is wrong:

```
if(empty()){
        root->setElement(element);  //Si es null creem l'arrel i la retornem
        root->setParent(current);     
        return root;             
    }
```

the above checks `root == nullptr` will always be false, remove above code and update it as I have mentioned below how to set the base case.

null pointer being used as code reaches here even when `node` is null:

```
if(element<=node->getElement()){
```

getElement will get called with node being null as above check is checking `root == nullptr` instead it should have been checking `node == nullptr`

And in main also you should ad break statement and a new statement most likely this could also be the cause of segmentation fault as mentioned below:

```
if(tree.empty()){
       root = new TreeNode;
       root->setElement(num); 
       break;
    }
    tree.insert(root,num);
```

In case you have already assigned root a valid object in constructor then ignore the new but keep the break. I hope you are setting left and right child of TreeNode as nullptr in constructor.

Also you are setting a dangling pointer in below line:

```
root->setParent(current);
```

`current` pointer has not assigned any value yet, I believe you wanted to retrieve value set in previous function call for `current` then you should be making `current` static as below:

```
static NodeTree *current;
```

The base case should be written as below:

```
if (node == nullptr)
{
        node = new NodeTree;
        node->setElement(element);  //Si es null creem l'arrel i la retornem
        node->setParent(current);     
        return node;
}
```

Could be more problems with your code as you have not shared complete code, below is a example of BST insert:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BstNode {

    public:
        int data;
        BstNode* left, *right;

        BstNode()
        {
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
        }
};

class Bst {
    private:
        BstNode* root;

    public:
        Bst()
        {
            root = nullptr;
        }

        void insert(int element)
        {
            root = insert(root, element);
        }

        BstNode* insert(BstNode* node, int element)
        {
            if (node == nullptr)
            {
                node = new BstNode;
                node->data = element;
            }

            else if (root->data > element)
            {
                node->left = insert(node->left, element);
            }

            else
            {
                node->right = insert(node->right, element);
            }

            return node;
        }

        void print()
        {
            print(root);
        }

        void print(BstNode* root)
        {
            if (root == nullptr)
                return;

            cout << root->data << " ";
            print(root->left);
            print(root->right);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Bst bst;
    bst.insert(6);
    bst.insert(3);
    bst.insert(8);
    bst.insert(2);
    bst.insert(7);
    bst.insert(4);

    bst.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if empty() is return root==nullptr;
this means that when your tree is empty ,than you can't call 
setElement(num) on null pointer. you need to initialize it at first.
something like root= new root_type(), after that set corresponding value.

Comment: did you try to debug and find where exactly code is crushing? most likely you have some uninitialized memory.

Comment: yey well now I solved that segmentation fault problem but now when I add elements they get added twice sometimes wtf

Comment: please update the question with corresponding updated modified code to be able to get view it